# How to remove duplicate entries from database which as over 10000 records with no id field

Tags: mysql

I have database like the following with 10K rows. How to delete duplicate if all fields are same. I don't want to search for any specific company. **Is there a way to search and find any multiple entries with all same fields get deleted. Thanks**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a unique ID column?

Comment: nope i have 4 columns company name, city, state and country as u can see above

Comment: If you provide table structure then only it will help to solve this issue

Comment: How do you determine duplicate? Company name same or company name and country and city?

Comment: if all fields are same then determine duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This command adds a unique key, and drops all rows that generate errors (due to the unique key). This removes duplicates.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(title);
```

**Note:** This command may not work for InnoDB tables for some versions of MySQL. See this post for a workaround. (Thanks to "an anonymous user" for this information.)

**OR**

Simply creates a new table without duplicates. Sometimes this is actually faster and easier than trying to delete all the offending rows. Just create a new table, insert the unique rows (I used min(id) for the id of the resulting row), rename the two tables, and (once you are satisfied that everything worked correctly) drop the original table

Answer (score 0):

This below query used to find the duplicate entry using all fields:

```
Select * from Table group by company_name,city,state,country having count(*)>1;
```

Comment: unexpected keyword by

Comment: Can you please post what error you are getting @ phoenix

Comment: Select * from `companies_active_accounts`  by `Company_Name`,`City`,`State/Province`,`Country` having count(*)>1;

Comment: Static analysis:

8 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "by" at position 43)
Unexpected token. (near "`Company_Name`" at position 46)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 60)
Unexpected token. (near "`City`" at position 61)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 67)
Unexpected token. (near "`State/Province`" at position 68)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 84)
Unexpected token. (near "`Country`" at position 85)

Comment: Select * from companies_active_accounts group  by Company_Name,City,State/Province,Country having count(*)>1;

Comment: Group key word missing

Comment: Ok I got list of 200 companies how to delete them

Comment: If there is any unique value's in then table like id then only we can able to delete.So when you are creating table you should think of having unique values like 'id'. Its not possible to delete in this case.

Comment: actually i imported all data from excel. it had no id field

Comment: Create New table with same exact fields then use query like   " insert into Newtable Select * from companies_active_accounts group by Company_Name,City,State/Province,Country having count(*)>1;"   this newtable now consist of non duplicate values .after that truncate companies_active_accounts,then swap data from new table to companies_active_accounts.